# Symfony 6 Session RequestStack

Tags: php, session, cart, symfony6

I'm trying to create a Cart under Symfony 6.1.2

I want to add my product in my cart but i have this error message : `Warning: Undefined variable $session`

```
public function get()
{
    //return $this->session->get('cart');
    return $session->get('cart');
}
```

i've commented a line because i was using SessionInterface but this is not used anymore on Symfony 6.1.

I don't get where is my error so i'm there to have some help.

This is my Cart.php (with some commented lines from SessionInterface)

```
<?php

namespace App\Classe;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
//use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;


class Cart 

{
//private $session;
private $requestStack;

//public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
  public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
{
   //$this->session = $session;
   $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
}


public function add($id)
{
    $session = $this->requestStack->getSession();
    $cart = $session->get('cart', []);

    if (!empty($cart[$id])) {
        $cart[$id]++; 
     } else {
         $cart[$id] = 1;
     }

    $session->set('cart',$cart); 
    
    /* $cart = $this->session->get('cart', []);

    if (!empty($cart[$id])) {
       $cart[$id]++; 
    } else {
        $cart[$id] = 1;
    }

    $this->session->set('cart', $cart); */
}

public function get()
{
    //return $this->session->get('cart');
    return $session->get('cart');
}

public function remove()
{
    //return $this->session->remove('cart');
    return $session->remove('cart');
}


}
```

and this is my CartController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Classe\Cart;

use App\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class CartController extends AbstractController
{

private $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)

{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

/**
 * @Route("/mon-panier", name="cart")
 */

public function index(Cart $cart)
{
    $cartComplete = [];

    foreach ($cart->get() as $id => $quantity){
        $cartComplete[] = [
            'product' => $this->entityManager->getRepository(Product::class)- 
 >findOneById($id),
            'quantity' => $quantity
        ];
    }

    return $this->render('cart/index.html.twig', [
        'cart' => $cartComplete
    ]);
}


/**
 * @Route("/cart/add/{id}", name="add_to_cart")
 */

public function add(Cart $cart, $id)
{
    $cart->add($id);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('cart');

}

/**
 * @Route("/cart/remove/", name="remove_my_cart")
 */

public function remove(Cart $cart)
{
    $cart->remove();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('products');

}


}
```

If i miss something it would be kind to show me where is the mistake.

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution.

With ResquestStack, i was wrong doing this :

```
public function get()
{

return $session->get('cart');
}

public function remove()
{

return $session->remove('cart');
}
```

I've changed my returns with :

```
public function get()
{
    
    return $this->requestStack->getSession()->get('cart');
}

public function remove()
  {
    
    return $this->requestStack->getSession()->remove('cart');
  }

}
```

Now everything is ok, in case of someone was block in this kind of situation